# Xcode Error "No such module SwiftAudioEx" in Xcode 12 in React-Native-Track-Player

Tags: reactjs, swift, react-native

Eh estado trabajando en un proyecto desarrollado en Ubuntu el cual al momento de compilarlo en una Mac con el Xcode 13 ha generado el siguiente error **No such module 'SwiftAudioEx'** el mismo muestra como dependencia de react-native-track-player.. aslguna solución para que al fin pueda compilar esta app

Comment: Tienes un archivo `.xcworkspace` e instalaste los pods del archivo `podfile`?

Comment: Así mismo, tengo el archivo .xcworspace y tengo el podfile instalado

Comment: El modulo de SwiftAudioEx no lo encuentro entre los modulos de Swift en Xcode

Comment: Abriste el archivo `xcworkspace`? Si abres el archivo `podfile` está la línea que hace referencia a SwiftAudioEx?

Comment: En realidad no, al aplicar no me instala esa dependencia el pod install

Comment: Agrega la referencia en el `podfile` y con `pod install` ya debe funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes una Mac con procesador Apple Silicon –M1/M2– ve al *Pod target*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez selecionado en la siguiente pantalla añade a las arquitecturas exlcuidas "**arm64**"

[image]

En caso de que no lo hayas hecho en el *Project target* hazlo también.

**PD:** Si tienes compañeros que trabajan en Intel, en algunas situaciones, podría llegar a ocasionarle un problema.